# sequences on a LIFO stack

Tags: java, data-structures, lifo

I'm studying for a midterm and I need help with this question:

Suppose that an intermixed sequence of push and pop operations are performed on a LIFO stack. The pushes push the numbers 0 through 9 in order; the pops print out the return value. Which of the following output sequence(s) could occur?  Select all that are possible.

```
1 2 5 4 3 6 0 9 8 7

6 5 4 3 2 1 0 7 8 9

4 6 8 7 5 3 2 9 0 1

0 1 5 6 4 3 7 9 2 8

0 2 4 1 6 7 5 9 8 3
```

I believe the answer is:

```
6 5 4 3 2 1 0 7 8 9
```

Am I correct? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First one is Possible and sequence is:

```
push(0);
push(1);
pop();
push(2);
pop();
push(3);
push(4);
push(5);
pop();
pop();
pop();
push(6);
pop();
pop();
push(7);
push(8);
push(9);
pop();
pop();
pop();
```

Second one is also possible with sequence:

```
push(0);
push(1);
push(2);
push(3);
push(4);
push(5);
push(6);
pop();
pop();
pop();
pop();
pop();
pop();
pop();
push(7);
pop();
push(8);
pop();
push(9);
pop();
```

Third one is not possible because after printing `9` stack will contain `0 1` and `pop()` will give you `1` not `0`.

Also fourth is also not possible because after printing `9` stack will have `2 8` and you can not `pop()` `2` before `8`.

Fifth is also not possible because after printing 4 stack will contain `1 3` and `3` will be popped first.